# How to connect to RMAN in Java?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, rman

I don't know how to connect to RMAN in Java. Simple request don't work when I use command non-SQL, like RMAN etc... I'm gonna to make program like "ORACLE Secure BackUP", but how they connected to RMAN??

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe that there is a published API for interacting with RMAN other than the command line.  So if you wanted to create a program like Oracle Secure Backup that used RMAN, you'd probably have to invoke the RMAN executable from Java.  Which means that you'd probably also have to parse the output of the various RMAN commands in order to provide feedback to the user.

If you want to go down this path, you'd want to use the Runtime class in Java.  Here is an example of [calling an external program from Java](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0014.html).

Comment: So, is it possible in Java? If yes, please tell me how to do it? How to send command to RMAN and how to get request?

Comment: @Mario Tim - Updated my answer with a link that shows how to call an external application.