# Oracle OCI API RMAN Commands

Tags: oracle, database-administration, oracle-call-interface, rman

When I try to execute the "`delete noprompt archivelog until time ‘SYSDATE-1’;`" command using "`OCIStmtExecute`" function , 

I am getting an error like
  "`ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended`"

Is this the correct command to delete `ARCHIVE` logs?
 Whether it is possible to execute `RMAN` commands using `OCI` API ? Are there any `OCI` functions to delete `ARCHIVELOGS` (log truncation) ?

Comment: probably try removing the semicolon(`;`)

Comment: Thank You for your fast response . I have tried the same without semicolon and got the same result .Please advice me further .

Comment: Looks like this is not possible. The link in this answer might help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4762706/how-to-connect-to-rman-in-java